# zsh fzf search path is strange on Mac

Tags: shell, filesystems, zsh, fuzzy-search, fzf

I installed fzf for the zsh on my Mac

I use`cd **` `<Tab>` , instead of getting a list of directories which can get into

I always get a long list of directories,such as

> [image: Blockquote]

How to solve this problem?

when I search specific file, it always return a list of library container files of Mac file system, how to ignore them and just leave the real one.
it takes a very long time to get the top1 real result
[image]

BTW the first line numbers [image] seems going infinite, why is that.

Answer (score 0):

[fzf default command](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/764316a53d0eb60b315f0bbcd513de58ed57a876/src/constants.go#L63) search every files in your home diretory and follow every symbol links e.g. `~/Library/Container/*/Downloads` which return files multi times.

According to the [readme of fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#environment-variables), you can specify `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` and `_fzf_compgen_path()` `_fzf_compgen_dir()` to exclude directories what you don't want to see.

```sh
# Use fd (https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) instead of the default find

# remove -L of fzf default command
# export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="find . -mindepth 1 -path '*/\.*\' -prune -o -type f -print -o -type l -print 2> /dev/null | cut -b3-"
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='fd --type f'

_fzf_compgen_path() {
  fd --hidden --follow --exclude ".git" . "$1"
}

# Use fd to generate the list for directory completion
_fzf_compgen_dir() {
  fd --type d --hidden --follow --exclude ".git" . "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the answer above:

- install `fd` on your Mac via `brew install fd`
- add the above mentioned code with FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND to your .fzf.zsh (which you then need to load from your .zshrc via `[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh`)
- edit .fdignore file in your home dir to include dirs that you don't want to be included